# Raspberry Pi Buildroot Gstreamer gst.h no such file

Tags: gcc, makefile, cross-compiling, raspberry-pi3, buildroot

I am trying to complete a video tutorial I found on YouTube to compile a customized version of linux to the Raspberry Pi (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=84T-P5ye864). The compilation proceeded for hours before I woke up the next morning, and it had stopped at 99%, and I had gotten this error. I then proceeded to install libgstreamer and many other packages in attempt to get this file. It seems that nothing that I do allows buildroot to see the gst.h file. I don't know what to do, I even manually included the path in the .mk file for gstreamer. Nothing seems to have worked.

```
[ 99%] Built target webkit2gtkinjectedbundle
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/user/Downloads/buildroot-2018.02.7/output/build/webkitgtk-2.22.2'
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/user/Downloads/buildroot-2018.02.7/output/build/webkitgtk-2.22.2'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/user/Downloads/buildroot-2018.02.7/output/build/webkitgtk-2.22.2'
[ 99%] Building C object Tools/MiniBrowser/gtk/CMakeFiles/MiniBrowser.dir/main.c.o
/home/user/Downloads/buildroot-2018.02.7/output/build/webkitgtk-2.22.2/Tools/MiniBrowser/gtk/main.c:32:21: fatal error: gst/gst.h: No such file or directory
 #include <gst/gst.h>
                 ^
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: This shouldn't happen, clearly. Did you do a fully clean build, or did you change something after you started building for the first time? webkitgtk checks for the presence of the gst library before building, so this really should not happen. Can you upload you .config file to a pastebin for evaluation? BTW, note that StackOverflow is not really the place to report issues; you're better off on the Buildroot mailing list or IRC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with most things like this, it can be solved with a simple

```
make clean
make all
```